# Division by a constant

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, integers

After skimming [Multiplication by a Constant is Sublinear (PDF)](http://www.lirmm.fr/~imbert/pdfs/constmult_arith18.pdf), ([slides (PDF)](http://ge.tt/6343C5u/v/0), [slides with notes (PDF)](http://ge.tt/6343C5u/v/1)) I was wondering if this could be extended to division by a constant in sublinear time?

Additionally, what about division with a constant numerator, ie. "division of a constant"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Division by a constant can always be recast as multiplication by a constant followed by a shift.  The relevant papers are:

Robert Alverson, "Integer Division Using Reciprocals," *IEEE Int'l Symp Comp Arithmetic*, (ISCA-10):186-190, 1991.

Torbjörn Granlund and Peter L. Montgomery, "Division by Invariant Integers using Multiplication," *ACM Conf on Prog Lang Dsgn and Impl*, (PLDI-1994):61-72.

Daniel J. Magenheimer, Liz Peters, Karl W. Peters, and Dan Zuras, "Integer Multiplication and Division on the HP Precision Architecture," *IEEE T. Comp.*, 37(8):980-990, August 1988.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look at those. Any ideas for division *of* a constant?

Comment: It's been a long time since I read any of these, but if I remember correctly the Granlund and Montgomery paper gives the algorithm for calculating the reciprocal.  When dividing _by_ a constant you move the cost of calculating the reciprocal to compile time, when dividing anything by a variable you have to calculate the reciprocal dynamically.  Which is pretty expensive: [I wrote a routine to do this on a MIPS-like 32-bit processor about 15 years ago](http://ipa.ece.illinois.edu/mif/pubs/web-only/Frank-RawMemo12-1999.html) and it took about 55 cycles.