# A question on the BSS model with inequalities allowed

Tags: complexity-theory

Let $k,M\in\Bbb N$ be fixed. In the BSS model we allow only $+,-,\times,=$ as valid operations and also an initial set of constants that are fixed for all instantiations of the algorithm. Here we relax $=$ and add $\geq,\leq$ operations.

Fix an upper bound on inputs and call this $M$.

Problem $1$ Given input $ka$ for some $a\in\Bbb N$, what is $a$?

Problem $2$ Given input $a^k$ for some $a\in\Bbb N$, what is $a$?

Is there an algorithm for both problems whose runtime depends only on $k$ using only ring operations only?

Comment: 1. What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking and to show us what you've tried in your question.   2. The obvious algorithms are division and binary search; did you try either of them?  Also, can you define "step" more precisely?  Which operations are allowed?  And, would you count $O(\log_2 (M/k))$ as better than $O(\log_2 M)$?  In particular, are you treating $k$ as a constant or as a parameter that varies?

Comment: @D.W. $k$ is constant here and hence $M/k$ improvements do not count. I am looking preferably an answer that is as close to $O(1)$ if possible.

Comment: @D.W. Ring operations preclude division.

Comment: I still think the question needs to be clearer.  By Problem 1 do you mean "Given $k,M$, compute $\lfloor M/k \rfloor$"?  As it stands, it looks like Problem 1 has many valid answers, including $a=0$ (there are many values of $a$ that satisfy $ka<M$).  If you want to prove a lower bound you'll need a more precise statement of the problem that you want a lower bound for.

Comment: And again, please tell us in the question what you've tried.  This will help us tailor an answer to your needs, and avoid repeating something you already know.

Comment: @D.W. $0\notin\Bbb N$. Lower bound is trivial $1$ step to decide if $ka=k$ output $1$.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether we can divide a large number by a constant, in $O(1)$ ring operations.  Some related facts and reasons to doubt that it's possible: [division by a constant has equivalent complexity to multiplication by a constant](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14954/755) (running time, not ring operations); [if you can add, multiply, and divide arbitrary-size integers in $O(1)$ time, you can solve every PSPACE problem in polynomial time](http://www.computational-geometry.org/mailing-lists/compgeom-announce/2003-December/000852.html); (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) and $\lfloor M/k \rfloor$ is not expressible as a polynomial in $M$ (for fixed $k$) with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$ [I know this doesn't take into account $\le,\ge$].

Comment: Thank you. 

$1$ What is the best complexity known for division by constant using ring operations and inequalities when the input is bounded?



$2$ I am uninterested in $\lfloor M/k\rfloor$ (related to 20 questions problem in BSS model). I am interested only in $ak/k$.